# How can users manage themselves in Joomla?

Tags: module, components, joomla1.5

Is there any component or module to manage profile by the users themselves in Joomla?
1)manage personal information, uploading profile photo and manage upload links
2)add/delete/invite friends

Comment: What version of Joomla? How much of a profile do you want them to keep? Do you plan to let users interact with each other?

Comment: joomla 1.5, profile means picture,invite another user and if possible user can each other

Comment: In that case Barries is right on the money. Jomsocial is a great component worth every $ for the license. Community Builder 2.0 is supposed to be very good as well, but I am not sure when that is due to release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think community bulider http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities/210 or sobi2 http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/directory/1113 will fulfull your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Jomsocial is also a very good plugin, it is worth spending some bucks to get the license. Community builder is free, but some nice plugins has to be bought!

You may also want to look at messaging components like UddeIM.